# The getter 'length' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: length. The relevant error-causing widget was: /bottom_bar.dart:17:64

Tags: flutter, dart

The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length
The relevant error-causing widget was:
PanierScreen file:///C:/Users/AZMAK/Desktop/material-components-android-codelabs/java/FlutterProjects/flutter_login_screen/lib/pages/bottom_bar.dart:17:64.

I'm trying to send my product into a screen kart and I have the above error.
Indeed I add products to a list of products and I would like to display this list in my Panier_Screen widget which I can access thanks to a BottomBar. But after adding the product to my list, the added product does not appear in my Panier_Screen Widget. What to do ?

My Cart Screen

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_login_screen/Entities/Panier.dart';
import 'package:flutter_login_screen/Entities/Produit.dart';
import 'package:flutter_login_screen/pages/panier_item.dart';


class PanierScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final List<Produit> produit;

  PanierScreen({Key key,
    this.produit }) : super(key: key) ;

@override
  _PanierScreenState createState() => _PanierScreenState();
}

class _PanierScreenState extends State<PanierScreen> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    super.build(context);
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Panier",
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Panier"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child: ListView.separated(itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              print(widget.produit[index].designation);
              return  Card (
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    child: FittedBox(
                      child: Text("${widget.produit[index].prixvente} FCFA"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  title: InkWell(onTap:() {},
                      child: Container(child: Text("${widget.produit}".toUpperCase()))),
                  subtitle: Text("Total : ${widget.produit[index].quantite_vendue * widget.produit[index].prixvente}"),
                  trailing: Text("${widget.produit[index].quantite_vendue.toString()} x"),
                ),
              );
            },
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(),
                itemCount: widget.produit.length))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  @override
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

My BottomBar class widget :

```
class AppBottomBar extends StatefulWidget {
  AppBottomBar({Key key}): super(key:key);
  @override
  _AppBottomBarState createState() => _AppBottomBarState();
}

class _AppBottomBarState extends State<AppBottomBar> {
  static List<Produit> produit = new List<Produit>() ;
  int position = 0;
  PageController _pageController = PageController();
  List<Widget> _screens = [ HomeScreen(), ConsultationStock(), PanierScreen() ];

  int _selectedIndex = 0 ;
  void _onPageChanged(int index){
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index ;
    });
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int selectedIndex) {
    _pageController.jumpToPage(selectedIndex);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        children: _screens,
        onPageChanged: _onPageChanged,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      ),

    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
//        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
//         showUnselectedLabels: false,
//        showSelectedLabels: true,
//        currentIndex: position,
      onTap: _onItemTapped,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: _selectedIndex == 0 ? Colors.blue: Colors.grey,
              ),
              title: Text('Accueil', style: TextStyle(color: _selectedIndex == 0 ? Colors.blue: Colors.grey,))),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:
          Icon(Icons.shop, color: _selectedIndex == 1 ? Colors.blue: Colors.grey,),
              title: Text('Produits', style: TextStyle(color: _selectedIndex == 1 ? Colors.blue: Colors.grey,))),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Stack(children:<Widget>[ Icon(Icons.shopping_cart, color: _selectedIndex == 2 ? Colors.blue: Colors.grey,), Positioned(
                  left: 16.0,
                  child: Icon(Icons.brightness_1, color: Colors.red, size: 9.0,))
              ]),
              title: Text('Panier',style: TextStyle(color: _selectedIndex == 2 ? Colors.blue: Colors.grey,) )),
//          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.monetization_on), title: Text('Journal vente')),
//          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.settings), title: Text('Paramètres')),
        ],
    )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the output of  `print(widget.produit.length)` in `_PanierScreenState` build widget?

Comment: let me check it

Comment: The list to which you are getting the length is null so it cannot get the length on the null that's why it is giving the error length was called on null.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of PanierScreen has an optional parameter called produit

```
final List<Produit> produit;

  PanierScreen({Key key,
    this.produit }) : super(key: key)
```

But when creating it in `_AppBottomBarState` you don't give it a value so it initializes with a null value

```
List<Widget> _screens = [ HomeScreen(), ConsultationStock(), PanierScreen() ]; //produit = null if you don't explicitly give it a value
```

I see your List `produit` is already static in the `_AppBottomBarState` so just pass it as it is

```
List<Widget> _screens = [ HomeScreen(), ConsultationStock(), PanierScreen(produit: produit)];
```